# Using custom camera to capture the frames

Tags: android, twilio

It would be possible to use our own camera source from which we get the frames instead of using the camera source provided by TWILIO.
The use case I am asking about would be to be able to use our own camera with which to capture the frames in order to process them with a better quality than the one we get now. As we are doing now, we get the frames provided by TWILIO through the camera capture of the SDK.
To create the video track we have created a camera (Camara) that extends CameraCapturer and overrides the methods provided by that class.

```
cameraCapturer = new Camara(context, CameraCapturer.CameraSource.BACK_CAMERA, videoFrameListener);

VideoConstraints videoConstraints = new VideoConstraints.Builder().aspectRatio(AspectRatio.ASPECT_RATIO_16_9).build();

localVideoTrack = LocalVideoTrack.create(context, true, cameraCapturer, videoConstraints);
localVideoTrack.addRenderer(videoView);
```

All the posts I've seen refer to TWILIO 6.x version, in my case we are using a 5.1.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am not an Android developer, so the best I can do is point you to other places this has been answered.

According to [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-android/issues/83):

> This should be possible by writing your own custom `VideoCapturer` or extending the `CameraCapturer` or `Camera2Capturer` and intercepting the camera frames before they are sent to the SDK media engine. Both approaches are non-trivial tasks. I suggest you reference our [custom video capturer example](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/tree/master/exampleCustomVideoCapturer) to understand what is involved in writing a custom video capturer.

I imagine that creating your own `Camera` object that interacts with the capturers would also work.

If you have trouble with this, I would recommend raising an issue in GitHub on the [Twilio Video Android app](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-android), as the Twilio Video Android dev team pay attention to that repo.

As for the version, the Twilio Video Android latest is version 7. Version 5 is still supported, but version 4 will reach full end of life on November 1st 2021. I would recommend updating the SDK so that you can use the latest and stay up to date. There are guides for updating from [version 5 to 6](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/migrating-5x-6x) and from [version 6 to 7](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/migrating-6x-7x).